# ex_modify_instance_attribute and create_node has AuthFailure error use apache-libcloud AWS EC2 driver

Tags: libcloud

When I use AWS EC2 driver invoke create_node and ex_modify_instance_attribute API , I got this error:

raise InvalidCredsError(err_list[-1])
libcloud.common.types.InvalidCredsError: 'AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials'

But ex_create_subnet/ list_nodes API success , and I'm sure about I have the permission on AWS IAM to create EC2 instance.
By the way , I am using AWC cn-north-1 region.

Answer (score 0):

I find create node with some parameters will got AuthFailure 
The Code:

```
 node = self.conn.create_node(name=instance_name,
                              image=image,
                              size=size,
                              ex_keyname=ex_keyname,                                                   
                              ex_iamprofile=ex_iamprofile,
                              ex_subnet=ex_subnet,                                                    
                           ex_security_group_ids=ex_security_group_ids,
                              ex_mincount=ex_mincount,
                              ex_maxcount=ex_mincount,                                                    
                        ex_blockdevicemappings=config['block_devices'],                                                     
                        ex_assign_public_ip=config['eth0']['need_eip']
                             )
```

I just delete some parameters and works:

```
 node = self.conn.create_node(name=instance_name,
                                                 image=image,
                                                 size=size,
                                                 ex_keyname=ex_keyname,
                                                 # ex_iamprofile=ex_iamprofile,
                                                 ex_subnet=ex_subnet,
                                                 # ex_security_group_ids=ex_security_group_ids,
                                                 ex_mincount=ex_mincount,
                                                 ex_maxcount=ex_mincount,
                                                 # ex_blockdevicemappings=config['block_devices'],
                                                 # ex_assign_public_ip=config['eth0']['need_eip']
                                                 )
```